# Insert + Select statements in one Query<T> gives ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, dapper

I'd like to do a simple INSERT-and-then-SELECT-it-query in one "run" with dapper, roughly like so:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO Table(Id, Value) Values(1, :value);" +
            "SELECT Id, Value FROM Table WHERE Id = 1;"

Connection.Query<Item>(query, new { value = value});
```

This just gives me `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`. If I run the exact same query (in "one run", with the params manually replaced) in Oracle SQL Developer, it runs fine.

If I split this in two, and do this:

```
var insert = "INSERT INTO Table(Id, Value) Values(1, :value);"
var select = "SELECT Id, Value FROM Table WHERE Id = 1;"

Connection.Execute(insert, new { value = value});
var item = Connection.Query<Item>(select);
```

...it works fine. I've tried removing the last semicolon (which seemed to be a *thing* in other questions), with no luck.

I've done this exact same thing with success in another project where I'm using SQL Server.

Using Dapper 1.42.

Can anyone see what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. In Insert add "Returning into Clause" and declare output parameters.

```
  var param = new DynamicParameters();
param.Add(name: "IinsValue", value: value, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
param.Add(name: "Id", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
param.Add(name: "Value", dbType: DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
Connection.Execute("INSERT INTO Table(Id, Value) Values(1, :value) returning Id,Values into :id, :value", param );
var Id = param.get<int>("Id");
var Val = param.get<String>("Value");
```

Comment: I'll check this out on monday (cant access the db from home), thanks!

Comment: Looked a bit more at this now, and the point sortof disappears if I just get a long list of params. I want to use the object mapping in Dapper, which was the whole point. Thus I have to use `Query<Item>(...)` or some form of it.

Comment: All until it seems like that won't be possible in this scenario. Seems like this is the only way to do these two operations in one query.